# Deploying a shiny app gives different results compared to when I run it locally

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that runs smoothly locally. It also runs very well after I deployed it as a web app. 
It gets multiple .CSV input files that I use for different analysis. In one case, I notice significant difference in the results I get (returned as table output) between the app and when I run it locally. The one that runs locally being correct.

What could be creating this difference? This is a bit baffling for me and any help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks,
Yonas

---------------Additional comments

It is very hard for me to show the code as it is a big one and a bit difficult to pin point where the issue is happening. I am attaching the same output table with different outputs when run locally and right after I deployed it. The error is localized to the two columns in most cases. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfuwx.png)

Comment: Maybe you have updated the data locally, but forgot to do the same on the server?

Comment: Not really! I have even tried the deployment multiple times after the first try just in case, with the same end result.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you're attempting and what results you're seeing? It's hard to guess why you're seeing unexpected results if we haven't seen what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have added additional info. above, if that adds anything..